# Skype User-Agent redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I am not an expert in htaccess but would like to make a redirect but seems like it doesn't work as I expect.

I have following rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (SkypeUriPreview)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://blog.yuppi.com.ua/server/crawler_proxy/routee.php?path=%1 [NC,L]
```

And I would like this request 
http://blog.yuppi.com.ua/share/post/one-two-three

Redirect to http://blog.yuppi.com.ua/server/crawler_proxy/routee.php?path=/share/post/one-two-three

Instead I recieve

http://blog.yuppi.com.ua/server/crawler_proxy/routee.php?path=SkypeUriPreview

Answer (score 1):

In your `RewriteCond`, `(SkypeUriPreview)` will capture `SkypeUriPreview` in `%1`.
In `RewriteRule`, `(.*)` will capture the path to `$1`. See [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html#InternalBackRefs) for a more visual example.

In your rule, replace `%1` with `$1`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (SkypeUriPreview)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://blog.yuppi.com.ua/server/crawler_proxy/routee.php?path=$1 [NC,L]
```